# How do I indicate I'm "merged" with a fork I'm already up-to-date with?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I'm developing a fork of some FOSS project on GitHub, for which I've looked into all other forks and incorporated all relevant changes. But - I've done that work not via pull-requests, but just using simple manual patches.

Now, I would like to claim that my fork has merged with the other forks. Unfortunately, if I try to create a pull request for one of them using GitHub, the interface tells me my fork is already up-to-date so a pull request is unnecessary.

Can I circumvent that somehow? Perhaps with command-line git commands?

... to be more concrete: [My project](https://github.com/eyalroz/ssb-dbgen/), [a fork I want to get pull request from](https://github.com/alanbernstein/ssb-dbgen/).

Comment: Why would you prefer manual patches to pull requests? Just to clarify.

Comment: You could link to your project, and then tell us which PR on which site from which branch to which branch you were trying. It seems you do not quite understand the concept of a pull request.

Comment: @cst1992: It was even more complicated than that, and, anyway, it was the first time I worked on a GitHub project with forks and I was (more of) a newbie.

Comment: @tkruse: See edit.

Comment: Are you sure you're choosing the right forks and right branches in the Github web UI? If the branches are not at the same commit, you should be able to create a pull request, even if the content is the same. You _can_ do it on the command line, by creating a remote, merging from it, and pushing the result to your repo. But it shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your repository, click new Pull request. In the next page, select:

your own eyalroz/ssdbgen as 'base fork', and the other alanbernstein/ssdbgen as head fork - *and make sure to select the branch with the latest commit for the other repository*.

like here:
https://github.com/eyalroz/ssb-dbgen/compare/master...alanbernstein:month-typo-fix

After creating this, your project should have a new open Pull request, that you can merge.

Comment: It was the patch branch! That's what I missed.